# How to expose build step results using docker + Google Cloud Build

Tags: node.js, docker, next.js, google-cloud-build

I'm trying to build a next.js application on Google Cloud Build in a monorepo using Yarn workspaces. I've found that one of our slowest points during the build process is installing node modules since we have to do it in a few different folders. Ideally, I'd like to leverage Docker to handle the caching of `node_modules` if nothing has changed. My Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM node:10.13
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install -g yarn
RUN yarn
COPY . .
```

My cloudbuild.yaml is below:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: [ 'build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/dashboard-modules', './packages/dashboard' ]
- name: node:10.15.1
  entrypoint: yarn
  # `yarn build-dev` relies on the installation of `next` that happens in the previous step
  args: ['--cwd', 'packages/dashboard', 'build-dev']
...
```

My expected result is that upon first build, `COPY package*.json` will view the contents of package.json and if nothing has changed, it will keep the same output for `node_modules`. One very critical step here is that we install `next` which is used later in the build process to build the app itself from `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "next build",
  ...
}
```

However, when I get to the second step in `cloudbuild.yaml`, my build errors with `env: 'next': No such file or directory`.

It seems that I need to somehow "surface" (for lack of a better term) whatever happens in the first step of `cloudbuild.yaml` and make the `next` command available to the second step. My question though is how can I do that?

I should note that I'm fairly new to Docker and trying to wrap my head around how it works.

Answer (score 3):

The philosophy of Cloud Build is that we are daisy-chaining steps together to build a result (commonly either a single new docker image or artifacts to be written to GCS).  Each step in the Cloud Build recipe is itself run in its own docker container instance.  The sharing between each step is the data contained at `/workspace` which is a shared volume.  The thinking is that each step will add some value to the build by manipulating the data at /workspace.

Your first command in your Cloud Build recipe causes a new Docker image to be built and that image stored in the local cache of Docker images.  However, the commands that are described in your Dockerfile are executed IN that Docker image in order to build the image.  They won't make any changes to your /workspace environment and hence there will be nothing "new" to be picked up in your second Cloud Build step.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. This all checks out to me. I guess the question I still have though is the "how". It seems that other steps allow for the "surfacing" of that first Docker image's result. Is it possible or am I totally mixed up on how to use Docker in this context?

Comment: You can create a docker image (say ... for example ... outside of the Cloud Build story) ... and use a container instantiated from that docker image as a step within Cloud Build.  See https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/create-custom-build-steps